# Is carbon tetrachloride an electrolyte?

Tags: electrochemistry, halides, covalent-compounds

Is $\ce{CCl_4}$ an electrolyte all by itself, or does something need to be added to it so that it becomes an electrolyte?

Also, is it *weak* or *strong*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, $\ce{CCl4}$ is not an electrolye.  An electrolye is a material that causes ions (charged entities) to form in the solvent.  Carbon tetrachloride neither dissociates into ions nor induces ion formation in the solvent.

The reason is that the $\ce{C-Cl}$ bond is rather strong and won't break under
normal solution conditions.  Nor does the molecule have any net dipole moment.

Answer (score 0):

$\ce{CCl4}$ is a non polar covalent compound. It consists of only molecules. Thus, it cannot conduct electricity and is a non-electrolyte.

Comment: I'm relatively new to this community, and am wondering WHY this answer has 2 "down" votes, with absolutely NO plausible explanation.